# How to Have Multiple Developers on a Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I'm still new to developing, but I want to know how me and my friend can both develop on the same Ruby on rails application. I have already started the application on my own computer, and now want to have ability for both of us to develop it. I think one solution might be using Github, but I am really unsure.

Any advice on how to enable multiple people to develop the same rails application?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of what language you're developing with, source control management is the way to go for team development. There are a ton of SCM options, including Git, Subversion, Concurrent Versioning System, and Mercurial.

Git is the preferred SCM option for RoR development, however you are not bound to using GitHub to host your repository. Nonetheless, GitHub is a good option for hosting your source code repository if you choose it.

Comment: CVS = Concurrent Versioning System ;). Not that you should use it (same to SVN)

Answer (score 2):

Yes Git with Github it's the best way, but i advice you to open an project in Teambox or BaseCamp or another project manager app

Good work !